# Find sum of this convergent series

Tags: convergence-divergence

find the sum of the infinite series

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{2^i}{n^{(2^i)}}$ for $n>1$

I tried the following

$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{4}{n^4}+...=k$

$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}(1+\frac{2}{n^2}+...)=k$

But it is not helping because the denomenator of $8$ will become $n^6$

Comment: Is the denominator $n^{(2^i)}$ or $(n^2)^i$?

Comment: I believe it is easy to show that for $n=2$ this sum is transcendental. So if the sum can be done in closed form, it will require some real cleverness.

Comment: @Mark Fischler it is $n^{(2^i)}$

Answer (score 0):

There is no expression for this series in "standard" functions.  The series $f(z) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty z^{2^i}$ is a well-known example of a [lacunary series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function) (but with no generally accepted name), and this is $ f'(1/n)/n$.